# WCF Parameter not Passed

Tags: asp.net, wcf-client

I call the following local WCF Client service.

```
var Key = 1000;
FormServiceClient formService = new FormServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IFormService");
```

And I call

```
formService.GetCaseData(Key);
```

The **Key** value is not getting passed into the service via my asp.net application.
If I used WCF Test Client then there is no problem working.

When I hit this step--> formService.GetCaseData(Key); 
 The Key parameter has a value of 1000.
Once I get to the Service side, it has a value of 0.

I noticed that if I call an method that returns a simple POCO class it works fine. I am trying to return an Entity Domain object. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Why do you think it's not being passed in? Have you tried debugging/stepping into the service?

Comment: I added a comment to the issue.

Comment: I noticed that it works for my simple POCO object. Does not work when returning an Entity Domain object. Is this known to be a problem?

Comment: To confirm, are you having problems passing a simple `int`, or are you having problems passing a custom type/class/model/etc? If the latter, it is more than likely a serialization issue - if debugging, check output window for associated issues

Comment: Did you maybe change the service contract on the server side and forget to update the client-side proxy after that??

Comment: The POCO object is what I am returning . I used the WCF test client to test the service and I can pass the int value via the WCF test client tool but then I get a separate error when returning the Entity object.So I have 2 problems. When calling the service via code, it does not pass the int value. When passing the value using the wcf test client tool it errors out when returning an entity object

Comment: Is WCF known to be able to serialize EF domain Entities?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. Although I have not yet found a solution, anyone reading this may want to unclick 'show my code only'. If you do you may see a System.Runtime.Fx.Async.Thunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(AsyncResult) or something similar. If this is the case, and you are using ASP.NET with  .NET 4.0+ the problem is likely a synchornization conflict between WCF and ASP that occurs only in debugging, and only when passing data through interfaces. However I know of no solutions to this problem.